# How to pass random IDs stored in py file as part of Json request body in Python (PyTest)

Tags: python, json, pytest

I am exploring pytest to automate test activities. I'd like to pass `var` values store in one .py file, which is outside 'TestCases' folder. JSON body is:

```js
req_json= "{ \r\n\"ReqParamList\": { \r\n  \"StdValue\": \"age@name\" \r\n } \r\n}"
resp = requests.request("POST", cURL, data=req_json, headers=headers, params=eid)
```

Age and name are fetched from DB and stored in as var in a separate py file

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errors
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="hostname",
        port=port,
        database="dbname",
        user="uname",
        connection_timeout=5,
        password="pw")
# Fname
    FnameCur = cnx.cursor()
    RandomFname = ("select fname from firstnames limit 1")
    FnameCur .execute(RandomFname)
    for row in FnameCur :
        fname = (row[0])
    print("fname is:", fname)
# Lname
    LnameCur = cnx.cursor()
    RandomLname = ("select Lname from lasttnames where Lname in (select "
                   "Lname from (select Lname from lasttnames ORDER BY RAND("
                   ") limit 1)t)")
    LnameCur.execute(RandomLname )
    for row in LnameCur:
       Lname = (row[0])
    print ("Lname is:",Lname)
except Error as e:
    print("Error", e)

finally:
    if (cnx.is_connected()):

        fnameCur .close()
        LnameCur.close()
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: what does your "separate py file" looks like ? where is it stored ?

Comment: In same project.. with a different folder.. It has mysql.connector import statement followed by few select queries using RAND option to pull random values...

Comment: Err... doesn't really answer my question... You really should [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly (if you hope to get any serious help I mean).

Comment: Sorry for that.. this is my first attempt.  BTW edited the info.. does that help

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Edited the main question.. is it helpful?

Comment: That's better indeed.

Comment: Ok, may I suggest that you read about [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) ? To make a long story short: the code doing the DB queries should be wrapped into a function returning `fname` and `lname`. Then in your test files, you import this function, call it to get your values, and build your json from those values. Also, you want to build your json from a Python `dict` you pass to `json.dumps()` - this is much safer (and simpler !) than trying to build it by hand as a string.

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot